# How to assign variables to each of the values in a row in an associated array

Tags: bash

The script will ask for a color scheme when executed. Color schemes are organized in a file in this way:

```
$ cat schemes
sch-001=red blue white
sch-002=green yellow black
```

An associated array is clearly called for here. Further, depending on the scheme, each of the colors should be used in another (nested) script or command. In a script it should look like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

... (The initial part of the script) ...

declare -A assscheme
mapfile -O 1 -t inscheme < schemes  #I prefer keys starting with 1

for val in "${inscheme[@]}"; do
   key=${val%%=*}
   value=${val#*=}
   assscheme[$key]=$value  
done

echo "${!assscheme[@]}"
echo "${assscheme[@]}"

read -p " Select color scheme: " color  #Let's say I've selected sch-001
echo "$color"

if [[ "$key" == "$color" ]] ; then


# I can't think of anything further yet.
#  And then I need something like this.

magick ......... -fill "$red" ...........
.........................................
script1 .......... -b "$blue" ...........
.........................................
script2 .......... -o "$white" ..........

fi

... (Continue the script) ...
```

How can I organize it this way? Or is there another way?

Comment: Aside: `declare -p assscheme` is a much more reliable/unambiguous way to display the contents of an associative array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option might be to utilize `grep` and `cut` to extract the colors for a chosen scheme into an array and then access the individual array elements for the colors.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Select color scheme: " scheme
printf "SCHEME: \n\t%s\nCOLORS: \n" "$scheme"

read -ra colors <<<"$(grep "$scheme" schemes.txt | cut -d= -f2)"
printf '\t%s\n' "${colors[@]}"

# Access the individual array elements as ${colors[0]}, ${colors[1]}, etc.
printf "First color: %s\n" "${colors[0]}"
```

Example:

```
$ ./script 
Select color scheme: sch-001
SCHEME: 
        sch-001
COLORS: 
        red
        blue
        white
First color: red
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea using the `bash/select` command to prompt the user to select items from a dynmically built menu:

```
$ cat scheme.1.bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

unset      schemes scheme color
declare -A schemes

while IFS='=' read -r key value                            # split input on '='; 'key' == text on left of '='; 'value' == text on right of '='
do
    schemes[${key}]="${value}"
done < schemes

select scheme in "${!schemes[@]}" 'Quit'                   # build menu from array indices + literal 'Quit'; user is then prompted to select from the menu
do
    if [[ -z "${scheme}" ]]                                # if no selection then ...
    then
        echo "invalid scheme; select again ..."            # print message and let 'select' prompt for a new input
    elif [[ "${scheme}" = 'Quit' ]]                        # if user wants to exit the menu then ...
    then
         echo "exiting ..."
         unset scheme                                      # unset our variable and ...
         break                                             # break out of the 'select'
    else
        select color in ${schemes[${scheme}]} 'Quit'       # build a new menu based on the colors of the chosen scheme + 'Quit'; prompt user to select from menu
        do
            if [[ -z "${color}" ]]                         # if no selection then ...
            then
                echo "invalid color; select again ..."     # print message and let 'select' prompt for a new input
            elif [[ "${color}" = 'Quit' ]]                 # if user wants to exit the menu then ...
            then
                echo "exiting ..."
                unset color                                # unset our variable
                break 2                                    # break out of both 'select' loops
            else
                break 2
            fi
        done
    fi
done

# display results

typeset -p scheme color                                    # display contents of variables
```

**NOTES:**

- if user chose `Quit` at any time then one or both of the variables (`scheme`, `color`) will be empty
- in place of the `typeset -p scheme color` OP can add code to validate both variables are set before proceeding with further processing

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./scheme.1.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 4
invalid scheme; select again ...
#? 1
1) green
2) yellow
3) black
4) Quit
#? 7
invalid color; select again ...
#? 2
declare -- scheme="sch-002"
declare -- color="yellow"

$ ./scheme.1.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 2
1) red
2) blue
3) white
4) Quit
#? 4
exiting ...
declare -- scheme="sch-001"
-bash: typeset: color: not found

$ ./scheme.1.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 3
exiting ...
-bash: typeset: scheme: not found
-bash: typeset: color: not found
```

---

If all you need is to select the scheme, then process all colors associated with said scheme we just need the first `select`, eg:

```
$ cat scheme.2.bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

unset      schemes scheme
declare -A schemes

while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
    schemes[${key}]="${value}"
done < schemes

select scheme in "${!schemes[@]}" 'Quit'
do
    if [[ -z "${scheme}" ]]
    then
        echo "invalid scheme; select again ..."
    elif [[ "${scheme}" = 'Quit' ]]
    then
         echo "exiting ..."
         unset scheme
         break
    else
         break
    fi
done

unset colors

if [[ -n "${scheme}" ]]
then
    read -ra colors <<< "${schemes[${scheme}]}"                # split array value on white space and store in array colors[]

    typeset -p colors                                          # display contents of colors[] array

    for color in "${colors[@]}"                                # loop through colors and ... 
    do
        echo "${scheme} : ${color}"                            # print scheme/color combo
    done
fi
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./scheme.2.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 4
invalid scheme; select again ...
#?                                  # user hit <Return> so 'select' displays entire menu:
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 3
exiting ...

$ ./scheme.2.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 1
declare -a colors=([0]="green" [1]="yellow" [2]="black")
sch-002 : green
sch-002 : yellow
sch-002 : black

$ ./scheme.2.bash
1) sch-002
2) sch-001
3) Quit
#? 2
declare -a colors=([0]="red" [1]="blue" [2]="white")
sch-001 : red
sch-001 : blue
sch-001 : white
```